# Java SQLite cannot find column when column exists

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I'm working a project(Full source code [here](https://github.com/JacobHearst/Pokemon)) and as part of the project, I've created a Database class to make interfacing with the SQLite database easier and cleaner. I'm currently attempting to write a method that will use SELECT along with the given parameters to return a string array containing the results. The issue that I'm having is that when I run the program to test it, Eclipse throws `java.sql.SQLException: no such column: 'MOVES'`

But, when I look at the database in a GUI, it clearly shows the column that I'm trying to access, and when I execute just the sql in the same program, it's able to return the data.

This is the method that I've written so far:

```
public String[] get(String what, String table, String[] conds) {        
    try {
        if (what.equals("*")) {
            throw new Exception("'*' selector not supported");
        }
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT " + what.toUpperCase() + " FROM " + table.toUpperCase();
        if (conds.length > 0) {
            sql += " where ";
            for (int i = 0; i < conds.length; i++) {
                if (i == conds.length - 1) {
                    sql += conds[i];
                    break;
                }
                sql += conds[i] + " AND ";
            }
        }
        sql += ";";
        System.out.println(sql);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            if (table.toUpperCase().equals("DEX")) {
                String id = "";//rs.getInt("id") + "";
                String species = rs.getString("species");
                String type1 = rs.getString("type1");
                String type2 = rs.getString("type2");
                String hp = rs.getInt("hp") + "";
                String atk = rs.getInt("atk") + "";
                String def = rs.getInt("def") + "";
                String spa = rs.getInt("spa") + "";
                String spd = rs.getInt("spd") + "";
                String spe = rs.getInt("spe") + "";
                String ab1 = rs.getString("ab1");
                String ab2 = rs.getString("ab2");
                String hab = rs.getString("hab");
                String weight = rs.getString("weight");
                return new String[] { id, species, type1, type2, hp, atk, def, spa, spd, spe, ab1, ab2, hab,
                        weight };
            } else if (table.toUpperCase().equals("MOVES")) {
                String name = rs.getString("NAME");
                String flags = rs.getString("FLAGS");
                String type = rs.getString("TYPE");
                String full = rs.getString("LONG");
                String abbr = rs.getString("SHORT");
                String acc = rs.getInt("ACCURACY") + "";
                String base = rs.getInt("BASE") + "";
                String category = rs.getInt("CATEGORY") + "";
                String pp = rs.getInt("PP") + "";
                String priority = rs.getInt("PRIORITY") + "";
                String viable = rs.getInt("VIABLE") + "";
                return new String[] { name, acc, base, category, pp, priority, flags, type, full, abbr, viable };
            } else if (table.toUpperCase().equals("LEARNSETS")) {
                String species = rs.getString("SPECIES");
                String moves = rs.getString("MOVES");
                return new String[] { species, moves };
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Table not found");
            }
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Screencaps:

[image: Database structure]
[image: Data from learnsets table]
[image: SQL query]

UPDATE:
I wanted to double-check that the database viewer I was using wasn't messed up, so I opened up the terminal and ran

```
sqlite3 git/Pokemon/data.db
pragma table_info(MOVES);
```

Receiving this in response:

```
0|SPECIES|TEXT|0||0
1|MOVES|TEXT|0||0
```

Comment: @CL. What is just what's being selected, eg: SELECT SPECIES(what) FROM LEARNSETS

Comment: This is not valid SQL. Please show the actual contents of `what` that result in the error message.

Comment: the (what) in my response was to show which part of the SQL was defined by the 'what' variable. Here's the actual SQL without the parentheses. SELECT AB1 FROM DEX where SPECIES='Bulbasaur';
java.sql.SQLException: no such column: 'species'

Comment: The evidence indicates that this table does not have this column. What GUI are you using? How are you sure that you're looking at the same database file?

Comment: @CL. I'm using SQLite database browser on Ubuntu, and yes I'm sure because all the other tables and data is displayed and accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, for anybody else having this issue, make sure that the data you're trying to get from the result set is actually included in it. For example, if I call `SELECT SPECIES FROM DEX;` the result set won't contain other things like id, type, or any of those other columns, it will ONLY contain the species column. I'm not sure why it took me so long to figure this out, but there you have it.